# Limiting Group by output

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database I have different departments with different people assigned to them. I want to give 10% raise to all employees of each department and then add them so that I can have a total salary value for each department. However, those departments that have at least one employee with a lastname ending in 'ce' should not be listed. I have Reseach, administration, and headquarter departments. Only research and administration departments should be shown with their respective total salary values.

```
SELECT
dname
, SUM(1.1*salary) AS total_salary 
FROM
employee INNER JOIN department
ON dnumber=dno
WHERE lname NOT LIKE '%ce'
GROUP BY dname
ORDER BY total_salary DESC
```

This does what I want, except that all departments are listed. How could I modify these statements so that only correct departments show up?

Comment: If you want that `headquarter` department is not shown then you must use `'%er'` instead of `'%ce' and everything will work as you expect

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to manually manipulate it like that, what if I added other departments later on?

Comment: So, you want that details of emploees of only 'Research' and 'Administration' are shown?

Comment: Yeah, but the point is, only those departments that don't have an employee with a lastname ending in 'ce', which just happens to be Research and Administration.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT dname,

       SUM(1.1 * salary) AS total_salary

FROM   employee

       inner join department

               ON dnumber = dno

WHERE  dname NOT IN (SELECT dname

                          FROM   departments

INNER JOIN employees

ON dnumber = dno

                          AND lname NOT LIKE '%ce')

GROUP  BY dname

ORDER  BY total_salary DESC`

Comment: Looks good, dep_name is not part of my database, and if I use WHERE dnumber NOT LIKE (SELECT dnumber
 FROM departments   I get Subquery returns more than 1 row!

Comment: @Modaresi what's the name of the column that contain the department name? If I'm not mistaken, you want to show all department's total salary except those which have employees their last name `lname` ends with ce. Am I right ?

Comment: Your are spot on, the name of the column is dname.

Comment: @Modaresi updated. It would be very helpful if you posted your basic tables structures

Comment: Still getting the same error, here is my basic table structure. CREATE TABLE employee 
 (fname  VARCHAR(12),
  minit  CHAR(1),
  lname  VARCHAR(12),
  ssn  CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
  bdate  DATE,
  address VARCHAR(27),
  sex  CHAR(1),
  salary INTEGER(7) NOT NULL,
  superssn CHAR(9),
  CONSTRAINT pk_ssn PRIMARY KEY (SSN));

Comment: /* Department Table */
CREATE TABLE department 
 (dname  VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  dnumber INTEGER(2) NOT NULL,
  mgrssn CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
  mgrstartdate DATE,
  CONSTRAINT pk_dnumber PRIMARY KEY (DNUMBER),
  CONSTRAINT fk_mgrssn FOREIGN KEY (mgrssn) REFERENCES employee (ssn));

Comment: @Modaresi what is the same error, if more than one row, have you considered using `IN` instead of `LIKE` ?

Comment: By same error I meant, more than one row error. No, I haven't used IN yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d2.dname as dept_name, SUM(1.1*e2.salary) AS total_salary 
FROM employee e2
INNER JOIN department d2 ON e2.dnumber=d2.dno and d2.dname not like (
    select distinct(d.dname) as dept_name2 from employees e left join department d on e.dnumber=d.dno where e.lname like '%ce'
    ) as temp
WHERE e2.lname NOT LIKE '%ce'
GROUP BY dept_name
ORDER BY total_salary DESC
```

**Assumptions:**
1) `department_name` is the column in `department` table representing its name
2) `Research` and `Administration` are the exact name of the departments you want

Comment: try this new query...Tell me whether it helped or still there is some problem